# connect to mysql using php vpn

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssh, vpn

I have a php script that accesses a mysql database. It lives on a server that has been migrated to aws (amazon web services). This server hosts a website that used to live on a physical server part of a private network.

The databases are still on that private network. I need to connect to a mysql database that is on a server with no public ip address. There is a vpn set up for this network. 
I would like to ssh or vpn to the network from the aws server. 
This is just to query something once a day.

I tried exec('ssh -f -L 3307:PrivateMYSQLServer:3306 USER@VPNADDRESS') but could not get it to work.

Is there a one liner that I can insert into the php script?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You’ll have to set up the server in which your script runs to connect back to your network via your VPN client.

Alternatively, you can set up a site to site VPN between your data center and AWS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a correctly configured site-to-site VPN (and routing tables, security groups, etc.), one end in your VPC and the other end in your private on premises network, then you don't need to create an SSH tunnel. Just connect to your database and run the query.

Comment: Let's say server B is a database on my PC (installed via Mysql Server). Can server A (a remote shared hosted server) have access to it via a PHP script (simple PDO database connexion) with a VPN site-to-site configuration ?

Comment: @user2305415 - create a new question instead of commenting on a four year old thread.